# Yocto / Bitbake : How to recover after a build crash

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Quite a few times my build has crashed prob due to resource exhaustion. This usually crashes the terminal I'm building from as well. Anyway, when this happens my recipe is stuck in a deadlock, meaning I get some build errors when trying to re-build.

I've tried cleaning the recipe with all the cleaning options without any luck.
Then I've tried locating the build output of that recipe and manually deleting that to get yocto to build from a clean state, but no luck there either.
Finally the only option I've found that to get out of it is to nuke the whole tmp folder and completely re-build everything. Surely there has to be a better way.

Comment: What is the configuration of your build computer? And which recipe is giving error?

Comment: Really no particular recipe. Just the one that's currently building at the time of the crash. I would guess you could replicate it by killing the build process mid build. Seems to me that if a build killed at the wrong time it's state is corrupted from which I've had a hard time continuing from

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting resources by configuring the options below in **conf/local.conf**:

```
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "4"
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 4"
PARALLEL_MAKEINST = "-j 4"
```

To clean the recipes, try with cleansstate and if it persists, try with cleanall which will also remove the download:

`bitbake -c cleansstate <your-recipe-here>`

or

`bitbake -c cleanall <your-recipe-here>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Already done this to prevent crashes in the future. But my question is really about if it's possible to recover from a 'stale' recipe.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question, but a recipe executes a sequence of tasks do_fetch > do_unpack > do_patch > do_configure > do_compile > do_install > do_package ... You can force execute a specific task like `bitbake -f -c compile minicom` or clear all states with `bitbake -c cleansstate minicom`